# Parsing error: Expression expected when trying to access props variables in ReactJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

I'd like to export a props variable used in component render function, but I'm having trouble defining it.

```
export const exportTicket = {
    eventLocation: "",
}
...

public render() {
    let ticket = this.props.ticket;
     exportTicket.eventLocation = this.props.ticket?.eventLocation!;
...
```

Right now ticket? has a "parsing error: Expression expected" problem. 
I'm kinda new to react so I don't even know if this is the correct way/place to export it.

Thanks

Comment: Please include an example that we can try locally. As is, we cannot paste your code into a file locally.

Comment: my guess is that you are using an older version of typescript that doesnt support:
this.props.*?*.eventLocation